# Figure label in one color, figure text in another as a document rule

Tags: color, captions

By adding the following package with parameters, all captions for tables, figures etc. change color, font-size and distance between label and text:

```
%Caption formatting
\usepackage[font={color=red,footnotesize},labelsep=quad,width=.75\textwidth]{caption}
```

If I still want the text to be black and only the "Figure 1" label to change color, then I simply set it back to black manually in every caption at the moment:

```
\caption{\color{black} test caption text }
```

The result is perfect:

[image]

but can I make these different colors automatic along with the package parameters in the preamble so I don't have to add `\color{black}` in every single caption?

---

A code example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    %Character set
\usepackage{graphicx}           %Figures 
\usepackage{caption}            %Main caption for subfigures
...

%Caption formatting
\usepackage[font={color=red,footnotesize},labelsep=quad,width=.75\textwidth]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.png}
    \caption{Test caption text}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would really nice to post minimal but compilabel examples. It saves a lot of time for a helper to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `labelfont` to control the font of the label. You can also use `captionsetup` to treat figures and tables (and all compaitble self-defined floats) differently.

[image: steevenCaptionFont]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font={color=red,footnotesize},labelsep=quad,width=.75\textwidth,labelfont={color=blue}]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=blue},font={color=green!50!black}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \captionof{figure}{Buzy bee}
    \captionof{table}{pogo penguin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Johannes, you solve all my questions today. Thank you very much.

This works: `\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont={color=red},labelsep=quad,width=.75\textwidth]{caption}`